# How to set selected directory as current in vim (netrw)?

Tags: vim

I'm trying to do two things:

1. Select file in treeview press `c`, open a file, run `:pwd` and see a parent directory of the file.
2. Map `:Ntree .` to some key.

Let's see an example:

[image]

My cursor is on `main.scss`, now I try to press `c` to change tree root (also tried `cd`, `CD`), then open the file pressing enter and see `.../static/css/` path using `:pwd`. However the parent dir remains unchanged. What's going on?

Regarding mapping, I just need the following: `nmap <somekey> :Ntree .`? Or there is special way to map when I is in the netrw plugin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, netrw's browsing directory is not the same as vim's notion of the current directory (done for backwards compatiblity with the explorer in vim v6)  (also see  :help g:netrw_keepdir).  It doesn't affect tree roots; for that, use :Ntree [dirname].

I tried a mapping:

```
map <leader>nt :Ntree<cr>
```

and it works as expected.  Be sure you have a netrw v150 or later, though -- :Ntree wasn't introduced until Jan, 2014.